# Fail2ban socket permissions reset on reboot

Tags: permissions, systemd, service, fail2ban, socket

I have some specific group/permissions set for my `fail2ban.sock` file to make Zabbix able to monitor Fail2ban as described here https://github.com/hermanekt/zabbix-fail2ban-discovery-

I added the following lines to systemd service configuration to make sure the permissions will be correct after service restart:

```
[Service]
ExecStartPost=/bin/sh -c "while ! [ -S /run/fail2ban/fail2ban.sock ]; do sleep 1; done"
ExecStartPost=/bin/chgrp fail2ban /run/fail2ban/fail2ban.sock
ExecStartPost=/bin/chmod g+w /run/fail2ban/fail2ban.sock
```

It works perfectly when I'm trying to restart the service manually using `systemctl restart fail2ban`. But for some reason, it does not work after the reboot.
I tried adding some debug lines to `ExecStartPost` with dummy `echo` and they are there, so `ExecStartPost` actions are being executed. But looks like something else re-writes permission on boot.
Any ideas on how to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 1):

This looks possibly like a "timing" problem - maybe the first of your `ExecStartPost` timed out or multiple `ExecStartPost` entries don't evaluated serially and running in parallel (due to specified `Type` of unit or some other setting), or something similar...

You can try to rewrite it in single line or in some script and use single `ExecStartPost` parameter, or...

Why just don't set default acl for `/run/fail2ban` directory (e. g. in `ExecStartPre`), so the socket gets created with correct permissions initially?
See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1315/452987

So try something like this:

```
ExecStartPre=-/bin/mkdir -p /run/fail2ban && /bin/setfacl -d -m g:fail2ban:rw /run/fail2ban
```

Another variant would be simply to set another path to fail2ban socket to some persistent directory (e. g. `/opt/fail2ban` instead of `/run/fail2ban`) either with `-s` parameter in systemd unit or with parameter `socket` within `/etc/fail2ban/fail2ban.local`. And set the permissions persistently.

Comment: Don't know what was the problem but I resolved it with the same commands moved to a separate script: `ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/bash -c "/lib/systemd/system/fail2ban-fix-socket-permissions.sh"`

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using a systemd service unit, it would worth creating a [systemd socket unit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.socket.html) as well.  By creating the socket unit, systemd will manage the socket file.  Ownership and permissions can be set with `SocketMode`, `SocketUser`, and `SocketGroup`.  Then in your service unit, in section `[Unit]` add `Requires=yourservice.socket`.

Comment: Thank you Paul for the tip, unfortunately fail2ban remove the socket file if already existing. Cf: line 249 of https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/master/fail2ban/server/asyncserver.py